# Existence of an metric or a topology so that every subset is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be a infinite set. Is there a metric on $X$ such that every sub set of $X$ is compact? What about a topology on $X$?

I think that if we can answer first question then we can answer the second question. I can't answer first question, but I can answer the second question: we can use indiscrete topology $\{ \emptyset , X\}$.If exist this meter must every subset of $X$ both open and close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is Hausdorff and every subset of $X$ is compact, then every subset of $X$ is closed, and hence every subset of $X$ is open. So we necessarily get the discrete topology. Since $X$ with the discrete topology is itself compact, we must have that it's finite, thus contradicting your assumption.

So no, as soon as $X$ is Hausdorff, and metric spaces are Hausdorff, this cannot happen.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on why "every subset is both open & closed" implies discrete?

Comment: The discrete topology is the one, in which everything is open, and we deduced that every subset is open.

Comment: Why does it follow that $X$ is finite?

Comment: Because every subset of $X$, and so $X$ in particular, is compact, so the open cover of $X$ given by the 1-point sets $\{x\}, x\in X$ (which are open since all subsets are open) has a finite subcover, so $X$ can be covered by finitely many 1-point sets.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is **No**. If this were possible for a given infinite set $X$, then every subset would be closed. So every subset would also be open, including one point subsets. That means that it' s the discrete topology.

Comment: Compact sets are only nexessarily closed in a Hausdorff space. The indiscrete topology on any set satisfies the OP's condition.

Comment: @MikeMiller - recall that the OP asked about metric spaces with this property, and these are Hausdorff.